# Simple Delphi 3d functions

Tags: delphi, graphics, 3d, freepascal, fpc

Could anyone help me with examples of some bare-bone, old school 3d methods in Delphi? Not using openGL or firemonkey or any external library (vanilla canvas coding). What i want to do is to be able to rotate X number of points around a common origo. From what i remember from the old days, you subtract left from right (on the 3d points) so that origo is always 0,0 - then perform the calculations, and finally add the left/top pixel offset to get the actual screen positions.

What im looking for is a set of small, ad-hoc routines, ala:

- RotateX(aValue:T3dpoint; degr:float):T3dPoint;
- RotateY(--/--)
- RotateZ(--/--)

Using these functions it should be fairly easy to create the old "rotating 3d cube" (8 points).

Also, are there functions for figuring out the visible "faces"? If i want a filled vector cube, then i guess i need to extract visible regions (based on distance/overlapping?) which in turn is drawn as X number of filled polygons? And these must no doubt be sorted by depth to not come out a mess.

for instance:

- PointsToFaces(const a3dObject:T3dPointArray):TPolyFaceArray;
- SortFaces(Const aFaces:TPolyFaceArray):TPolyFaceArray;

Any help is welcome!

Comment: I also confuse them, but in Delphi it is called `real`, not `float`.

Comment: Why not at least get glScene?

Comment: Because i will be compiling under Smart Mobile Studio, which compiles object pascal to javascript. And openGL is not supported on Safari Mobile. I just wanted the basics so i could learn by playing around with it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here are some nice good-old resource for [Delphi Math](http://www.efg2.com/Lab/Library/Delphi/Graphics/Math.htm) from [efg's Reference](http://www.efg2.com/).
You can find a [list of graphic projects](http://www.efg2.com/Lab/Graphics/index.html).
[2D/3D Lab Vector graphics](http://www.efg2.com/Lab/Graphics/ThreeDLab.htm): translation, rotation, scaling, view transform, homogeneous coordinates, clipping, projections, vectors, matrices etc...

Comment: A bit overkill for my needs but the source shows the mathematical function names so it gives me a good startingpoint. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I did write a simple 3D rendering 'engine' a few years ago, using only naïve linear algebra. Might not be the most efficient one, though. A few thousand of points is the limit if you want to be able to move reasonably smooth. [Sample EXE](http://privat.rejbrand.se/d3grphing.exe). You can get [the code](http://privat.rejbrand.se/d3grphing.txt) if you like, but it might not be that pretty.

Comment: I should mention that I very soon abandoned my prototype in favour of OpenGL, which is used in [AlgoSim](http://www.algosim.se).

Comment: I am going to convert the code to smart mobile studio, so opengl is not an option yet. Its just to Get the basics right